# How to read the plist file of ANOTHER app on Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, bundle, plist

I am creating a plugin to another application which I would like to access one plist file.

I tried the following, but the file can't be found.

```
NSBundle* bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] initWithPath:@"~/Library/Containers/com.Apple.Externalapp/"];
NSString* filePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"container" ofType:@"plist"];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSLog(@"File exists");
} else {
    NSLog(@"File doesn't exist");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting with `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. That method returns the NSBundle for your application, completely initialised. You send an `initWithPath` message to this initialised bundle; things will go very wrong from then on.

You probably want `[[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath... ]`.